# Array to string conversion en una consulta SQL Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Tengo esta consulta SQL en Laravel

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cantidad, DATE(fecha) AS fecha_registro FROM prueba AS p
        LEFT JOIN motivorechazo AS m ON m.id=p.motivorechazo_id
        JOIN estado AS e ON e.id= p.estado_id
        JOIN registro AS r ON r.id= p.registro_id
        JOIN nodo AS n ON n.id = r.nodo_id
        WHERE DATE(fecha) LIKE '%$fechames%' 
        AND estado_id NOT IN (1, 200,253,170) 
        AND estado_id < 250 
        GROUP BY fecha_registro"));
```

En la parte de GROUP BY fecha_registro me aparece el error de **Array to string conversion**, como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: ¿Cómo en la parte del `GROUP_BY`? ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta el mensaje de error completo pulsando en [edit]?

Comment: Por que no intentas colocar la consulta solo en el select y no en el raw, ej: DB::select("tuconsulta"); y después de eso adjuntar mas información del retorno del problema.

Answer (score 1):

El error ocurre por que estás tratando seguramente de imprimir un vector o una matriz con una instrucción del tipo `echo`.

Pudieras por ejemplo crear un modelo `Prueba` que esté vinculado a tu tabla `pruebas`

Ahora:

Además de lo anterior, sería mas simple *(considero)* hacer uso del *query builder* para componer dicha consulta, pues estás dejando totalmente de lado las ventajas de este mismo:

```
$data = Prueba::selectRaw("COUNT(*) AS Cantidad, DATE(fecha) AS fecha_registro")
              ->leftJoin('motivorechazo', 'motivorechazo.id', '=', 'prueba.motivorechazo_id')
              ->join('registro', 'registro.id', '=', 'prueba.registro_id')
              ->join('nodo', 'nodo.id', '=', 'registro.nodo_id')
              ->whereDate('fecha', 'LIKE', '%'.$fechames.'%')
              ->whereNotIn('estado_id', [1, 200, 253, 170])
              ->where('estado_id', '<', 250)
              ->groupBy('fecha_registro')
              ->get();
```

Ahora como estarías obteniendo una colección de datos, entonces se hace necesario que los recorras con un bucle, por ejemplo un `@foreach`

**Referencias**

- [WhereDate en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)